# Visualizing a manifold created using DimensionReduce

Tags: plotting, differential-geometry, dimension-reduction

Apologies if the question is too vague, please delete if so.

I am trying to understand Manifolds in general (if there is any recommended text?) and how to use the function `DimensionReduce`

Does the data need to be of a particular form or can a set of data of the form  `data=Table[RandomReal[], 3,100]` ~ `{{0.368934,0.923998,0.367269}...}`

Using `DimensionReduce[data,3]`

be used to show a relationship?

Is there any recommended way to plot the new data?

Can the resulting 3D shape show anything about the data? An example data I tried had this effect:

Original data plot

[image: Original data plot]

`DimensionReduce` data plot

[image: DimensionReduce data plot]